# If it is so difficult to see god through mantra japa, why should we do it

Tags: gods, mantras, vedic-gods, siddhi, manuscripts

What is the use of mantra japa if it’s really difficult to attain siddhi of any mantra for physical interaction or getting any wish fulfilled by god. If materialism doesn’t matter in our lives, what is the meaning of the present materialistic existence of humanity.

Comment: Which spiritual practice is easy by any means? Going by your logic we should not indulge into any of those? When the goal is highly rewarding the effort that we must put in should be equally great. This is true for all aspects of life not just about spiritual practices.

Comment: There several factors in mantra Siddi foremost is brahmacharya that is why all baba  who attained mantra Siddhartha lived alone in cave

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it is as difficult to attain parmatma (God) as much difficult it is to realise the true self. As the true self is God from the very beginning. Realising this is attainment of moksh. Choosing how to realise it is a path of your deciding. One may realise it by chanting mantras, other might realise it by studying hard sciences. Someone else might do the same doing mundane chores throughout the day. As to which path to achieve realisation, is right or wrong, is totally a silly question to ask.

Coming to the meaning of life. I assume you are asking meaning of this current life. Technically, its meaningless, as, if not in this one, you may attain realisation in the next one. Then if there is no meaning, that means life is purposeless? No... Not at all.
Purpose of life are 4 fold. Follow dharm, attain arthic stability. Follow Kam to enjoy pleasures. And lastly moksh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).